# Why does my laptop shut down, does it get too hot?

Tags: laptop, cpu, shutdown, fan, overheating

When I play games, or use powerful-applications such as Autodesk Maya, my laptop just shuts down, ofcourse without any warning at all.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Cleaned my fan, completely!
- Checked if I have enough RAM and good enough graphics card, and I do.
  (6 GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce GT540M with 2 GB VRAM)

None of these options worked. Even tried to clean my fan twice!

Now, I have some options I could also try, but I don't know if that have anything to do with it or not. I was thinking reinstalling my Windows 7, because maybe it has to do something wrong with the installation?

My laptop is about a year old, and this problem just happend out of no where, short after I downgraded from Windows 8 Release Preview to my original Windows 7.

Comment: Re-installing the OS is *very* unlikely to do any good. Far more important than the fan itself are its exhaust vents. How exactly did you clean the fan? Did you disassemble the laptop?

Comment: Yes, i did disassemble the laptop, and got to hold the fan in my hand and ofcourse cleaned it with both compressed air and canned air. None of this worked.

Comment: As I said: Nevermind the fan. Did you clean the exhaust vents (where the air leaves the laptop)?

Comment: OH, didn't see that. Yea i did also clean that.

Comment: Have you checked the temperatures?

Comment: I have indeed. When im not playing or using applications. The temperatures is around 60-65 °C, and when i am playing or using powerful applications, it gets to about 85-100 °C, and then it shutsdown.

Comment: Then it's obviously overheating. Check your heatsink and the heat paste that connects it to the CPU.

Comment: You can try some base with fans that make your computer cooler in order to prevent overheating.

Answer (score 2):

You could do some things in order to prevent overheating

- Prevent your computer being over clothes or blankets, this avoid heat air goes out from your computer.
- Use a base with fans, some computers have bad architechture and this makes processor overheat more than others, the base will cool making temperature stay low.
- If it's possible, try to play videogames without other process running in parallel, avoiding over processing.
- Check the computer doesn't make noises, this could make hardware function in a bad way and overheat the computer.

The optimal temperature for processors is bettwen 50°C-85°C, for HDD is below 70°C, so if the ranges are above those, you must buy some kind of cooler to prevent damages and therefore shutting down the computer.

Actually, the cooler is the hrdware, the best is the performance, remember that superconductors works at very low temperatures, so if you want better performance, not only preventing shutting down, but also durability, this could be your best shot.

Answer (score 1):

The heat sink is probably coming loose from the CPU.  Modern CPUs have thermal cutoffs.

Comment: Well, in this case, i actually checked the whole computer when i disassembled it, and nothing was loose at all.